Transmitter and Receiver Circuit
How can I use a 12 MHz crystal in the circuit instead of an LC oscillator?
I want it to be very little weight for a plane. It doesn't need to be super long range. I don't have a variable inductor or capacitor.


LC component weights compared to crystal weight is about equal. Crystals in this circuit will likely turn on sluggishly compared to LC, so that data must slow down a great deal.

@DeepShankarHalder say that in your question, not in a comment ... comments are not for adding information to the question

Consider a plane carrying a "9 ft" antenna crashing.
